# Websites in Firefox become unresponsive for ~30 seconds and then return to normal on their own

Tags: windows-7, firefox, freeze

In the past weeks, suddenly my Firefox started behaving really weird - a few times a day the currently opened tab becomes unresponsive (you can't click or hover anything) but you can still scroll through them (at least a bit - after that point, it's just plain white). At these times, the cursor is the hand one or the arrow one during the whole unresponsiveness episode, regardless of what you're pointing at, it just gets frozen in the last state. You also can't close the tab during this tab - the only way is either to wait a good 30 seconds for it to unfreeze or to change to a different tab and close the unresponsive one. When you do change tabs, though, the newly opened tab sometimes disappears completely, with a radial loading circle appearing in the middle of the screen for a few seconds before it magically reappears (it does *not* reload, though!). From what I've been able to observe, this tends to appear on content-heavy websites like Reddit, Facebook, Google Images or YouTube most often but it does happen on sites with less content as well, just not as frequently.

Tried reinstalling Firefox - to no avail. Tried Safe Mode - didn't help. Neither CPU or RAM usage is high during the unresponiveness episodes

What is happening? I haven't changed my browsing habits in the past weeks, nor have I installed any new add-ons. I've tried disabling the ones I have but it's still happening with them turned off. What else may I try?

(Also, I'm running Windows 7 if that's improtant)

Comment: Are you running the latest stable version (currently 60.0.1) of Firefox?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes I am

Comment: There's a lot of that going around.  It can be various causes--a hung script, waiting for content, leakage, etc.  I get that all the time when I have many tabs open, especially when the session stays open for a day or longer.  When the delays become a problem, I just close Firefox and restart it.

Comment: Have you tried running Browser Console at the same time? You may be able to see some activity related to the hang up. A while back I had such a problem and it turned out that my antivirus software didn't like some site activity.